# Play video file with VLC, then quit VLC

Tags: python, windows, vlc, subprocess

I am working on a simple Python script that is supposed to do something, then play a video file, and then do some more stuff.

I am forced to do this on a **Windows XP** machine with **Python 3.2.3** and **VLC** to play my video file.

I am currently using this code...

```
vlc_path = '\\path\\to\\vlc.exe'
video_path = '\\path\\to\\video\\file'
subprocess.call([vlc_path, video_path])
```

... to open VLC and play the video. It works nicely. However, the script waits for VLC to quit before it goes on. Which is good and I want to keep it that way.

My question is: **Is there a way to quit VLC right after the video file has been played?**

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: for additional control vlc has python bindings: http://wiki.videolan.org/Python_bindings

Comment: Thanks, bmu, but that's more than I need. :)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Funnily enough, vlc has a command line option for this:

```
  --play-and-exit, --no-play-and-exit
                             Play and exit (default disabled)
```

So, just pass this option to vlc.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. One thing that seemed to be important is that you set `shell=True`. This worked for me:
`subprocess.call([vlc_path, video_path, '--play-and-exit', '--fullscreen'], shell=True)`

Comment: @Florian. Strange. For me `shell=False` worked, and `True` didn't. However, thanks for your implementation!

Comment: This did not work for me running vlc on Windows 10. However adding the dummy item mentioned below did the trick.

Comment: remark: if loop playback is active, this won't work (makes sense though)

Answer (score 10):

Another option would be to pass the dummy item `vlc://quit`, e.g.:

```
vlc audio1.mp3 audio2.mp3 vlc://quit
```

---

Source: https://wiki.videolan.org/Transcode/#Completely_non-interactive_transcoding

Answer (score 1):

If nothing works try using the option `--ignore-config` at the beginning after `vlc` in addition to `http://quit` at the end

Answer (score 0):

Best way I can think of is killing the process by a separate thread after video length has passed, if you know the length of the video in Python. Elsewhere, it depends on VLC-s command line options. Maybe you can tell him to close after playing the movie.

Comment: It would be better to use the command line option here rather than uncleanly terminate the process.