# How to close/exit/quit Vlc Player in python on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, vlc

I am trying to write a simple program in Python on Ubuntu that will close/exit/quit VLC Player when playing video has completed.

Can you please guide me that what should I add in my program to get my required result.

```
import io,sys,os,subprocess
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
global process
name= askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Video Files","*.h264")])
myprocess = subprocess.call(['vlc',name])
```

Thank you

Comment: You can kill/terminate the process with myprocess.terminate() and myprocess.kill() respectively. But I don't know how you would go about checking whether VLC has finished playing a video.
One of my initial thoughts is to create a VLC plugin(using the python VLC API?) and somehow send a notification from that to your python program when the playback is stopped, but that has the inherent problem that if you have another vlc window open playing a video when that video stops a notification will also get sent.

Comment: @username_unavailable I tried both commands but these are not effective... still VLC Player is open

Comment: possible duplicate of [Play video file with VLC, then quit VLC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249261/play-video-file-with-vlc-then-quit-vlc)

Answer (score 4):

Use VLC's `--play-and-exit` command line option as so:

```
subprocess.call(['vlc',name,'--play-and-exit'])
```

so your final code would look like:

```
import io,sys,os,subprocess
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
global process
name= askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Video Files","*.h264")])
subprocess.call(['vlc',name,'--play-and-exit'])
```

**[Note:]** You may have to set `shell` to True or False for it to work properly as so:

```
shell_value = False  # or True
subprocess.call(['vlc',name,'--play-and-exit'], shell=shell_value)
```

**[Alternative:]** You can also instead include `vlc://quit` as the last 'file' to play as so:

```
subprocess.call(['vlc',name,'vlc://quit'])
```

Comment: how do I add these in my program

Comment: @Fahadkalis You can accept my answer to indicate that it solved your problem (this was the first answer).